# Making a video call through adb

Tags: user-interface, adb

Is there a way to make a video call through ADB?

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

Above works only for Voice.

Comment: I think that you are confusing between screen coordinates (the screen position of the icons) and device coordinates - the worldwide location of the device, as in GPS location...

Comment: Removed sub question about coordinates. Thanks TDG ! Yes I was looking for screen coordinates. Following site gave an idea on how to get them. (http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Found the cmd. Verified in Android 7.1.1 and it works !

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx --ei android.telecom.extra.START_CALL_WITH_VIDEO_STATE 3
```